# How to check compatible and optimizer version for a Oracle database

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, database-administration

How to check compatible and optimizer version for a Oracle database instance. I want to know if there is any specific command to check the above two versions from SqlPlus. For compatible version, I know following command might do the job:

```
select * from database_compatible_level;
```

I want similar command which will tell me optimizer version. Please help.

Comment: optimizer_features_enable initial parameter defines optimizer version in database.

Comment: @mohsen.b I tried with `SHOW PARAMETER optimizer_features_enable` command but it resulted in **ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.**. Any other alternatives?

Comment: try `select value from v$parameter where NAME = 'optimizer_features_enable'`

Comment: @FrankOckenfuss Just tried but returned nothing on the console!

Comment: replace equal sign (=) with like

Comment: @mohsen.b Thanks for the suggestion. I tried replacing **=** with **like** but it showed me **table or view doesn't exist**.

Comment: select value from v$parameter where name like '%optimizer_features_enable%'; also if you have permision show parameter command will work

Comment: @mohsen.b Actually I don't think the above permission will work without having admin permission which I don't have. So, it will be helpful if you know of other ways to get it which will not require admin permission. Just like I did for **compatible** version i.e. `select * from database_compatible_level;`

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands as sysdba to know the current values set for these parameters.

```
SQL>conn sys as sysdba

SQL>show parameter OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE;

SQL>show parameter COMPATIBLE;
```

Comment: I don't think the above permission will work without having admin permission which I don't have. So, it will be helpful if you know of other ways to get it which will not require admin permission. Just like I did for **compatible** version i.e. `select * from database_compatible_level;`

Answer (score 0):

Any database user can check the OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE setting by using the `EXPLAIN PLAN` command:

```
SQL> explain plan for select * from dual;

Explained.

SQL> select trim(plan_table_output) optimizer_features_enable
  2  from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => 'advanced'))
  3  where plan_table_output like '%OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE%';

OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('19.1.0')

SQL>
```

Viewing most database parameters require `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` or `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY`, but luckily this parameter is exposed in the Outline section of the explain plan. The value in the explain plan is technically only for the statement, but as long as you don't change the parameter at the session or statement level, the value from the above query will be inherited from the system parameter.